# How to hide that enum value in microsoft bot emulator?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

[image]

How to avoid that enum values like 1,2 ....i want hide it and i want to display my custom string

```
public enum Qst1
{
    Interact_with_many_including_strangers = 1,
    Interact_with_a_few_known_to_you
}

public enum Qst2
{
    Realistic_than_speculative = 1,
    Speculative_than_realistic

}

[Prompt("At a party do you: {||}")]
public Qst1 A1;
[Prompt(" Are you more:{||}")]
public Qst2 A2;
[Prompt("Is it worse to:{||}")]
public Qst3 A3;
return _order.Field(nameof(Questions.A1)).Field(nameof(Questions.A2))
```

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: public enum Qst1
    {
        Interact_with_many_including_strangers = 1,
        Interact_with_a_few_known_to_you
    };
    public enum Qst2
    {
        Realistic_than_speculative = 1,
        Speculative_than_realistic

    }